# WMS Layers from Azure Geoserver not loading with multiple users

Tags: postgis, geoserver, leaflet, wms, cloud-gis

I am loading multiple WMS layers into a leaflet web application from an Azure virtual machine Geoserver that pulls data from a PostGIS database on the same machine.

The layers load through quickly and work well with a couple of people using the application. However, once many people start loading the layers through multiple instances of the application the layers do not load.

I am looking for a steer on what the possible solutions to this may be as I imagine it will not just be one simple fix.

Comment: what error messages are in the "images" returned or the log file?

Comment: There is a config option for the maximum number of connections to the database.  Have you checked this?  It could be that it works until it hits this number then starts to fail.